# K8s Ingress re-directing to http app running outside the cluster in a VM - Not working

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

**Setup**

- VM running outside the k8s cluster is hosting the Web app running at port 5601 (Time being exposed via Public IP)
- We are accessing the app using the public IP which has login and other things. If we hit http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5601/, it will ask for login and works properly. What this means it will redirect to http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5601/app/login and works
- I have a k8s cluster with an ingress controller exposed via LoadBalance(LB) which is registered with Cloudflare.
- I create the service with no selectors and created the endpoints exposing the above ports as shown below
- > ```
  > apiVersion: v1
  > kind: Endpoints
  > metadata:    
  > subsets:
  > - addresses:
  >   - ip: 10.128.0.18
  >   ports:
  >   - name: opensearch
  >     port: 5601
  >     protocol: TCP
  > ```
- I created the ingress pointing to this service, and I could see that it has the backend for VM IP and Port.
- So when I hit this, it is going there but then, I get the error saying page not found for /app/login on nginx. What I understand is that when it is re-directing it is not going to VM rather it is coming back k8s ingress controller and it does not find anything on k8s.

  **So my questions is is it possible to expose via the path (/opensearch) to external service (It could be VM or domain name) which is not a static page. Meaning from k8s ingress hostname with path like this "app.kohls.com/opensearch" should get transferred to VM:port and it should work properly with login and other things.**

  - **So here app.kohls.com/opensearch ==> VM:port, but then it re-directs back app.kohls.com/app/login which does not exist. So how do I make it work everything with VM:port/app/login and other things, once it got re-directed from k8s ingress**
- I tried with the following annotations for nginx
- kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin:     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: true    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
- Is there any annotations that are possible to make it stay in the re-directed thing

Comment: VM and k8s clusters are in the same VPC, and I am trying to use internal ip, so that, It is not open to outside world

Comment: I can use specific annonation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect, but for this, I need to expose using the PublicIP, which I do not want to do
I want to use internal port of the VM which is in the same VPC

Comment: Which IP are you providing in Endpoint private or public ?